# Where should I migrate this question about HTTP/HTTPS?

Tags: support, migration

I have a question about HTTP/HTTPS on Superuser. It has not received any answers:
[SSL / https login issue](https://superuser.com/questions/484737/ssl-https-login-issue)

I was thinking of migrating it to [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), or perhaps [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Which site should I migrate it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't migrate this question anywhere as it's older than 60 days.

I think either target site would be fine. It's both an issue with a web site you maintain as well as a general security question.

Comment: Thanks. I have reposted the question on Webmasters and I have flagged the question on Superuser asking for it to be deleted (I was not allowed to delete it myself).